# How can I convert 2D POLYGON data to 3D polygon data? and plotting?

Tags: 3d, geometry, shapely

I have a 2D POLYGON vector. For example, when I run print(map['geometry'][0]), the result is:

POLYGON ((127.032790006694 37.4744929935236, 127.032814864098 37.4751960230234, 127.034762251212 37.4793748391478, 127.036184563118 37.4813147151527, ... ))

I want to convert this data to 3D (where all z coordinates are set to 1). How can I perform this conversion, and how can I plot the converted data?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgnsx.png)
.